# c++ Linked List with multiple pieces of data

Tags: c++, linked-list

We're going over linked lists in my class right now. Unfortunately, it's an online class. The only thing the prof is good for is grading, and I can't find the answer in my book. I would like to know if you could create a linked list with multiple pieces of data like this.

```
struct node{
    char grade
    string student        
    node *next
};

node *newNode;

newNode = new node;
newNode->student = "Jake";
newNode->grade = 'D';//Cause I don't like Jake
newNode->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Yes you can do this. But you're missing `;`s in the `node` definition.

Comment: @noobProgrammer It is very well written what the OP wants. Don't always try to be smart against low rep users.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay Thank you much. the missing ';'s is due to less than 4 hours of sleep a night for the last two weeks preparing for finals + work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could have as many types of data in a linked list as you'd need.

```
struct node{
    char grade
    string student        
    node *next
    typeOfData typeVariableName;
};

node *newNode;

newNode = new node;
newNode->student = "Jake";
newNode->typeVariableName = /*anything could go here*/;
newNode->grade = 'D';
newNode->next = NULL;
```